Two normal vector fields of a connected surface are equal or opposite

Let $S \subseteq \Bbb{R}^3$ a connected surface and $N_1, N_2$ two unit and normal vector fields. Then $N_1 = \pm N_2$ .

I had the following idea to proof this. Let $\Phi$ a regular parametrization of $S$. Since both $N_1$ and $N_2$ are normal, $\{ \Phi_u, \Phi_v, N_1\}$ and $\{ \Phi_u, \Phi_v, N_2\}$ should be basis. Consider $F: S \rightarrow S, a \Phi_u + b \Phi_v + c N_1 \mapsto a \Phi_u + b \Phi_v + c N_2$.
$F$ is smooth since it is polynomic (via propper basis change), bijective and its inverse $a \Phi_u + b \Phi_v + c N_2 \mapsto a \Phi_u + b \Phi_v + c N_1$ is also smooth, so it is a diffeomorphism. Also, notice that $F$ is linear, which means that $F = dF$ since the differential is the best linear aproximation of every map. My idea consits on proof that $dF = \pm I_3$, what would finish the proof. The problem is that I get so confused in terms of basis and change between them, so any possible help would be appreciated.

You're making this far too complicated. A regular surface has a tangent plane at each point. The orthogonal complement of a plane in $\Bbb R^3$ is one-dimensional, hence contains precisely two unit vectors. Now you need to argue by continuity  that for any continuous unit normal vector fields $N_1$ and $N_2$, the sets ${x\in S: N_1(x)=+N_2(x)}$ and ${x\in S: N_1(x)=-N_2(x)}$ are both open. Now can you finish?

@TedShifrin Yes, by connectedness one of those sets must be all $S$. This is brilliant, thank you so much!

Why don't you write up an official answer below? :)

@TedShifrin Could you tell me if what I wrote is fine? I have notice that maybe it is not necessary to use connectedness, only the fact that they are unit vectors on the same line.

Given $p \in S$, let $T_p S$ the tangent plane of $S$ at $p$. Then, its orthogonal complement, call it $V_p$, is one-dimensional (then is a line) . By hypothesis: $$N_1(p), N_2 (p) \in V_p \implies \exists \lambda(p) \in \Bbb{R} : N_2(p) = \lambda(p) N_1 (p)$$
Since both are unit vectors, $1 = \lVert N_2 (p) \rVert = \lVert \lambda(p) N_1 (p) \rVert = |\lambda (p)| \implies \lambda (p) = \pm 1 \implies N_2(p) = \pm N_1 (p)$.
This shows that $S = \{ p \in S : N_2(p) = N_1 (p) \} \cup \{ p \in S : N_2(p) = -N_1 (p) \}$
Since those are closed sets (they are the preimage of $0$ of $N_2 - N_1$ and $N_2 + N_1$ respectively) and $S$ is connected, one of them is $S$ and the other is empty, finishing the proof.

Aren't you missing precisely the point of being connected? You should prove that $\lambda$ is locally constant and then use connectedness, or use the open sets argument @TedShifrin provides in his comment above.

@WishYouTheBest You are right, I do not notice that $ N_2 (p) = \pm N_1 (p)$ (it can occur that some $p$ verifies $N_2 (p) = N_1 (p)$ but some $q$ might be $N_2(q) = - N_1(q)$ ) is not equivalent to $N_2 = \pm N_1$, thanks!
